# github sync from fork

Tags: github, synchronization, branch, git-fork

I am pretty new to github.

I made a fork from a third party, then I modified several files in this fork and committed to my fork. Based on my fork, I made a branch.

I noted there are some update in upstream (the third party source which I made the fork), so I sync my fork. Now how do I push the changes from my fork to my branch ?

Another situation is after I made some changes in my branch, how do I push them back to my fork?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a:

```
git request-pull original_repo <repo_url> repo_with_changes
```

This is will pull the new code into the original_repo

Here is more information on it: 
https://git-scm.com/docs/git-request-pull

Answer (score 0):

> Based on my fork, I made a branch. I noted there are some update in upstream (the third party source which I made the fork), so I sync my fork. Now how do I push the changes from my fork to my branch ?

Actually, if you have added a remote referring to the original repo, what you do is:

```
 git remote add upstream /url/original/repo
 git fetch upstream
 git checkout your-pr-branch
 git rebase upstream/master
 git push --force
```

This assume `your-pr-branch` was done from the `upstream` repo `master` branch.
You can also pull `upstream/master` into `master` and push `master` to your fork if you want to sync your fork.