# Resynching fork with original repo using Github commands only?

Tags: git, github

I created a fork and now that fork is many commits behind the original repo. There are many examples of resynching but they seem to involve git command line. I am wondering if there is a way to do this using Github itself in the same way the fork was created from Github.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As seen in this [blog post](http://discocid1.blogspot.com/2015/08/update-github-fork-from-web-only-in.html) (by [Priyanshi Parikh](https://plus.google.com/111566269796282794338)), you can make a pull request from your branch, except you switch base:

> - go fork on github , on right click "pull request"
> - click "new pull request"
>     You should see message "there isn't compare".
> - click "**try switching base comparison**".
>     This switch pull `forkedrepo:master ... fork:master` to `fork:master ... forked:master`.

(in your case, use your own branch, not `forked:master`)
(but do use `fork:master`)

> - type description "merge" , click "send pull request"
>     You'll see pull request going forked repo fork.
> - scroll bottom. should see "`this pull request can automatically merged`".
>     click "`merge pull request`"

```
click "confirm merge"
```

Comment: Is there a good reason why, where it shows the message indicating that the fork is behind X commits that there isn't a button that will just play the commits against the fork? Is it for safety reasons?

Comment: @Jeff Not that I know of. I suppose the same operation could be use to sync your main branch of your fork (which is behind)

Comment: Thanks. I could be wrong but this seems like a klugey way to do this and maybe the command line is better.

Comment: @Jeff I agree, and generally I do it locally: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42571507/6309. But that was not your original question.

Comment: yes thanks for the answer. Perhaps in the future Github will provide a more intuitive way of accomplishing this.